# Auto generate variable for return value of method

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I often find myself in a situation like this [image: Selection for List], and I find it really annoying, that I have to change the method by hand to something like

```
List<MPartSashContainerElement> list = sps.getChildren()
```

Is there any way, that on this very point shown in the picture, I can have the first part of the above assignment automatically added, such that

sps.[<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> - selection on getChildren()] may directly lead to the upper expression?

**UPDATE**

This became part of a bachelor thesis on postfix code completion, and the feature is right underway. If you want to know more check [Google Plus announcement](https://plus.google.com/103039009129837251052/posts/iyhhPr32BdB) or the [Postfix Template Implementation](https://github.com/trylimits/Eclipse-Postfix-Code-Completion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature will be realised by the newly implemented [Postfix code completion](https://github.com/trylimits/Eclipse-Postfix-Code-Completion), check the link for the update site or the above mentioned google plus post for more information.

Answer (score 3):

No. You can finish writing sps.getChildren(), then with the cursor in the getChildren selector, use Ctrl+1 to assign the result to a new local. There's no way to tell when you're "done" and ready to have the left-hand side of the expression inserted--you could be calling something on the result of getChildren(), after all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Maybe just a second proposal could be added just beneath this one, where I have a direct generation of the requested variable?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Adding an additionalcontent proposals as seen on the image
    getChildren() : List<MpartSashContainerElement>
    getChildren() : List<MPartSashContainerElement> (Create Variable)
or something like that! Would spare the CTRL+1 stuff :)